# Two data models in one view (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to display text boxes of two classes in one view. I use the Entity framework database first approach and don't know how to display 2 data models in one view. Also, I need to hide one of these class text boxes and show up on the click of a button.

Here is the first class "Task"

```
public partial class Tasks1
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Tasks1()
    {
        this.Sub_tasks = new HashSet<Sub_tasks>();
    }

    public int Task_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Start_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> End_date { get; set; }
    public string Assigned_dept { get; set; }
    public string Assigned_emp { get; set; }
    public string Priority_type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }
    public int Step_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Step Step { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Sub_tasks> Sub_tasks { get; set; }
}
```

This is the second

```
public partial class Step
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Step()
    {
        this.Tasks1 = new HashSet<Tasks1>();
    }

    public int Step_id { get; set; }
    public string Step_type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }
    public int Process_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tasks1> Tasks1 { get; set; }
}
```

The error I got.

[image]

please help me! if my question is stupid, please be kind enough to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pack these 2 models to 1 model, like this:

```cs
public class FullVM
{
    public Tasks1 MyTask {get;set;}
    public Step MyStep {get;set;}
}
```

So your cshtml can be written like this:

```
@model YourNamespace.FullVM


@Html.IdFor(model => model.MyTask.Assigned_emp)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyStep.Process_id)
```